# Bitwise XOR operation in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I'm learning bitwise operation and i came across a xor operation,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main
{
    printf("%d\n",10 ^ 9);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

the binary form of 10  ---> 1 0 1 0
the binary form of 9   ---> 1 0 0 1

So in XOR the output is 1 when one of the input is 1 and other is 0.

So the output of 10 ^ 9 is 0 0 1 1 => 3

So when trying for the -10 ^ 9, I'm getting the output as -1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main
{
    printf("%d\n",-10 ^ 9);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Can some one explain me how it is -1?

Thanks in advance for all who helps!

Comment: Your `-10` sign-extends. (which is why bitwise operations are generally done on *unsigned* types)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of bitwise and(&) of a positive and negative number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395317/meaning-of-bitwise-and-of-a-positive-and-negative-number)

Comment: What did you expect the answer to be? If you want -3, you could use brackets like `-(10 ^ 9)`, but I'm not sure what you are really wanting to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does C++ do bitwise "or" operations on negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326900/how-does-c-do-bitwise-or-operations-on-negative-numbers)

Comment: It is a duplicate question except that here its a c language and the post has c++, but the answer is already explained. So, do your search before asking a question !

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes i get the sign bit is present, can you explain more? on how the bits will be shown?

Comment: @JModi ok thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from the comment.

In a two's complement system, negative values are represented by values that are *sign-extended* to the width of the type. Where `10` is `1010` in binary, the two-complement representation for `-10` for a 4-byte integer is:

```
11111111111111111111111111110110
```

(which has an unsigned value of `4294967286`)

Now you see what happens when you `xor` with `9` (binary `1001`),

```
  11111111111111111111111111110110
^                             1001
----------------------------------
  11111111111111111111111111111111  (-1 for a signed integer)
```

The result is `1111` which is sign-extended to 32-bits, or `11111111111111111111111111111111` for a signed `int`, which is `-1`.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Sure, glad to help. To convert from positive to negative representations in a two's compliment system, you simply use bitwise negation (flip all bits) in the positive number and add `1`. (to get back, you just do it again)

Answer (score 7):

Because the operator precedence of XOR is lower than the unary minus.

That is, `-10 ^ 9` is equal to `(-10) ^ 9`.
`-10 ^ 9` is not equal to `-(10 ^ 9)`.

-10 is 11110110<sub>(2)</sub> and 9 is 00001001<sub>(2)</sub>.

11110110<sub>(2)</sub> XOR 00001001<sub>(2)</sub> = 11111111<sub>(2)</sub>

11111111<sub>(2)</sub> is -1 in 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 1):

Binary representation of negative numbers uses a concept called [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). Basically, every bit is first flipped and then you add 1.

For example, the 8-bit representation positive 10 would be `00001010`. To make -10, first you flip the bits: `11110101`, and then you add 1: `11110101 + 1 = 11110110`.

So the binary representation of -10 is therefore `11110110`

If you XOR this value with 9, it would look then look like this: `11110110 XOR 00001001 = 11111111`.

`11111111` is the two's complement of 1, therefore the final answer is -1.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The minus '-' sign have higher precedence than the xor '^' operator . So first we find the value of -10.

The binary equivalent of 10 is 1010 & representation in terms of 8-bits becomes 0000 1010 .

For signed numbers , we take a 2's complement of 10 .
     First find 1's complement of 0000 1010

```
   0000 1010  ----- 1's complement ---- 1111 0101
```

Now find 2's complement by adding 1 in 1's complement result .

```
   1's complement   ---------  1111 0101
   Adding 1         ---------          1
   2's complement   ---------  1111 0110
```

Now perform -10^9 (XOR operator gives 1 when both bits are different other wise it gives 0)

```
  -10   -------  1111 0110
    9   -------  0000 1001
 --------------------------
 -10^9  -------  1111 1111
```

-10^9 = 1111 1111 which is equal to the -1 in signed numbers.

Thats why the output becomes -1 .